# Replace innerHTML of div by <jsp:inclue>

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
function loadForm() {
    alert("hai");
    document.getElementById("divid").innerHTML="<jsp:include page='publisherform.jsp'></jsp:include>";
}

<a name="publisher" href=# onclick="loadForm()" >PublisherManagement</a>
```

Here, jsp:include is working at page load itself.... Can any one say the reason? how to load it on click?

Comment: You *must* have to use `jQuery.ajax()`.

Comment: Let me guess: JSP tags are not translated to HTML when inside javascript context. At best, it needs some escaping. The browser _won't_ understand `<jsp:include>`

Comment: @AVD not really, there's an alternative called code injection (not that it's nice).

Comment: @JanDvorak OP wants to request a *page* and filled out `div` with response on clicking.

Comment: @AVD Then code injection won't really _load_ anything. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is you cant because the jsp code is processed on the server before the html and JS is returned to the client. Once it is rendered you can no longer process JSP code.

To communicate back to the server you need to use Ajax.

Alternatively you can use an IFrame to load another page's content.